# Can I create a polymorphic key from a custom object?

Tags: custom-field, polymorphism, custom-object

I'm creating a custom object that needs to be related to multiple other objects (but only one per record). I.e. via a ParentId field it could be related to a Opportunity, a Contact, an Account, or another custom object.

This would be pretty much the same as the [Polymorphic Key](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm#soql_polymorph_keys) [Attachment.ParentId](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm) that can reference multiple other object types.

I can't do this via the UI as the lookup can only be related to a single type.

[image: New Lookup Relationship]

**Is it possible to create a polymorphic reference through another means, such as the metadata api?**

Failing that, are there any viable alternatives?

I'd like to use the lookup so I can show the related objects via the page layouts. This object will also be deployed as part of a managed package and clients may want to reference their own custom objects from it.

Comment: Is it viable to appropriate FeedItem / Event / Task / Note perhaps with RecordType?

Comment: @bigassforce Would you then link to the correct object type via a dedicated field, or just rely solely on different sets of fields with RecordType. Seems like it could be messy quickly. Especially if those objects are otherwise in use already.

Comment: Good question, the appropriateness depends on how taskful / eventful / noteful that "data" is. User may not want ToiletBreak__c on their calendar 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of now, polymorphic keys only exist as standard fields. See the idea - [Custom Polymorphic Id field (WhoId/WhatId)](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaview?id=08730000000BqzBAAS)

To mimic the functionality by say using a custom text field, would be a rigorous customization:

1. Custom text field, mark as ExternalId for indexing purpose.
2. UI control...probably would have to be custom visualforce + apex controller.
3. Related Lists...again, custom visualforce + apex controller.
4. Probably some other stuff I can't think of right now, but that would be the minimum as I envisage it.

Comment: This is the conclusion I'd come to, but I thought I'd try my luck to see if anyone had any other ideas. I'll add a link to an existing idea into your post.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link. Will look at it and likely vote it up!